# Parcheesi question

Tags: parcheesi

What if you have only one piece that is able to move, you throw a 2 & a 6.  Your opponent has a piece 4 spaces in front of you on a blue safety space and a blockade 8 spaces in front of you. Can you choose to use the 2 in order to be safe (thereby in able to use the 6) or must you use the higher die, move 6 spaces thereby putting yourself in jeopardy of being captured?  Remembering that you cannot move the full 8 spaces because your opponent has his blockade on that space.

Answer (score 2):

The Parker Brothers rules, which are available on Hasbro's website, are silent on the subject. https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Parchessi.PDF

The Milton Bradley rules explicitly state that you may use either the 2 or the 6, your choice. https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/Parcheesi.pdf

All other sources of rules copy these or, as in the Wikipedia entry, combine the two and add what one must assume are the article's author's favorite house rules because they are completely unsourced.